# How to assign a value to the space created by malloc in python?

Tags: linux, malloc, python-3.7, ctypes, memcpy

I was trying to assign a value (bytes) to a space created by malloc in python (Ubuntu 18.04 linux) but don't known how...

```
dllc = CDLL("lib.so.6")
malloc = dll.malloc
malloc.restype = c_void_p
malloc.argtypes = (c_size_t,)

#initialize a pointer using malloc and allocate a space of size 1032
ptr = malloc(1032)

#here is the sample value of size 1032 in bytes
value = b'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx......xxxxxxxx'
```

I actually tried using memcpy to copy the value, but the resulting value wasn't the same as the original one...

```
memcpy = dllc.memcpy
memcpy.restype = c_void_p
memcpy.argtype = (c_void_p, c_void_p, c_size_t)

#copy value to the space referenced by ptr
memcpy(ptr, id(value), 1032)
```

When i dereferenced the pointer, the value wasn't the same as what it was assigned

```
import ctypes

#dereference the pointer but the value doesn't match
ctypes.cast(ptr, ctypes.py_object).value
```

Can someone help please...

Comment: *memcpy.argtype**s***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `id` as you can just pass the bytes buffer to `memcpy`.

I'm on windows, so only the first line differs, but the rest of the code should work:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ctypes


def main():
    dll = ctypes.CDLL("msvcrt")
    malloc = dll.malloc
    malloc.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
    malloc.argtypes = (ctypes.c_size_t, )
    memcpy = dll.memcpy
    memcpy.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
    memcpy.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_size_t)

    alloc_size = 1032
    ptr = malloc(alloc_size)

    value = b"A" + b"X" * 1030 + b"B"

    assert len(value) == alloc_size

    # note that ctypes has a memmove method.
    # ctypes.memmove(ptr, value, alloc_size)
    memcpy(ptr, value, alloc_size)

    # cast the pointer to a char*
    pchar = ctypes.cast(ptr, ctypes.c_char_p)

    # print the first, some of the in-between and the last bytes.
    print(pchar.value[0], pchar.value[1:10], pchar.value[alloc_size - 1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output:

```
65 b'XXXXXXXXX' 66
```

Also notice that ctypes has a [`memmove`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.memmove) (so you don't need `memcpy`).

Comment: I tested it on linux with jupyter notebook, after memcpy, len(pchar) was 1034, but the value pchar.value[1:1032] was still a bit different...

Comment: Thanks for help, memmove is much better !!